# Windows 7, moved USERS folder (part) to different drive, need to restore to C:

Tags: windows-7

Moved USERS folder, or as much as allowed, to temporary on E: to gain space. Computer was inoperable. found moved USERS folder - not in root directory of E: but in another folder on E:. Tried copying USERS back to C: but screen display only partially restored. Any tech help gratefully received. N (ex computer engineer!)

Comment: How did you moved the users folder? We should change the location of the folder from properties\location,

Comment: Thank you for the reply Joy. I moved the folder with the contents that would move (not all would) to my server, then tried to move the folder back again! bit stupid, should have known I couldn't do this! Not sure what you mean with your second sentence re "properties\location" is this something I should know?